# How to determine whether the ssrs reporting-services ReportViewer control succesfully rendered

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

**Requirement**
Allow a user to Save a report's current parameters' state if the report successfully rendered. ie. All drop-downs are selected, empty fields that don't allow blank are filled etc.

**ReportViewer behaviour**
After the 'View Report' button is pressed, the report viewer performs some client side validation and displays an alert if all is not well; otherwise, the report is regenerated and the javascript function: pageLoad() is called.

**Possible Solution**

- Somehow add a handle to the 'View Report' click event and disable my
  'Save' button.
- Enable the 'Save' button in the pageLoad() method.

Is this the best way to implement the solution? If so, how do I get a reference to the 'View Report' button?

**ETA:**

Here's the code I'm using at the moment.
 - *btnViewReport* is the button that you see at the right-hand side of the parameters area in the ReportViewer.
 - *btnSave* is a button that I've added outside of the ReportViewer. It doesn't matter what it does. The important thing is it should only be displayed when *btnViewReport* is clicked and the report successfully generates (all required parameters are filled).
 - *pageLoad* is a function that is called, by the ScriptManager, everytime there is a partial callback. Clicking *btnViewReport* causes a partial postback.

```
    var firstTimePageLoaded = true;

    function pageLoad() {

        if (this.firstTimePageLoaded) {
            $("#btnSave").hide();
            this.firstTimePageLoaded = false;
        }
        else {
            $("#btnSave").show();
        }

        var btnViewReport = $('#<%=ReportViewer1.ClientID %> input[type="submit"][value="View Report"]');
        btnViewReport.unbind('click'); // pageLoad() is sometimes called twice.
        btnViewReport.click(function () {
            $("#btnSave").hide();
        });
    }
```

Now if I leave some parameter fields empty and click "View Report", the "Save" button will be hidden because a partial postback will not occur.

I need the firstTimePageLoaded flag to prevent the button showing when the page is initially displayed. It works but is right up there on my list of crappy work-arounds.

Comment: What is the "Save" button you mention? How are you including the ReportViewer on the page? Can you elaborate a bit on the "Possible Solution" section, show some code, markup or mockup of what you're trying currently?

Comment: Hi, I've added some code and more information. Hopefully that'll help.